# Retrofit JSONLD ERROR on Android (Java/Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit2, api-platform.com

i am trying to retrieve a JSON response that looks like this :

```
    {
  "@context": "/api/contexts/Advert",
  "@id": "/api/adverts",
  "@type": "hydra:Collection",
  "hydra:member": [
    {
      "@id": "/api/adverts/6",
      "@type": "Advert",
      "id": 6,
      "title": "PS5 Neuve !",
      "content": "Je vends la toute nouvelle Playstation 5, le prix est non négociable.",
      "author": "Jonathan Kaekr",
      "email": "JonhatanK@hotmail.fr",
      "category": "/api/categories/2",
      "price": 995,
      "state": "draft",
      "createdAt": "2020-11-25T09:29:13+00:00",
      "publishedAt": "2020-11-25T09:33:59+00:00",
      "image": null
    },
```

But when i try to retrieve it with Retrofit it gives me this error : **Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $**

This the files that i use :

Interface.kt :

```
 package com.example.lebonangle.data

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface LeBonAngleApi {

    @GET("http://192.168.1.10:8000/api/adverts?page=1")
    fun getAdverts(): Call<List<Adverts>>
}
```

Class.kt :

```
package com.example.lebonangle.data

class Adverts {
    var title: String? = null
    var content: String? = null
    var author: String? = null
    var email: String? = null
    var price: Int? = null
}
```

and the function that i use in my mainActivity :

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(advertUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val service = retrofit.create(LeBonAngleApi::class.java)
        val adverts = service.getAdverts()

        adverts.enqueue(object: Callback<List<Adverts>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Adverts>>, response: Response<List<Adverts>>) {
                val allTanStop = response.body()
                allTanStop?.let {
                    for( advert in it) {
                        Log.d("ADD","Annonce ${advert.title}")
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Adverts>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("ADD", "Error : $t")
            }
        })
```

Comment: your response not a JSON format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according Call<List> api , We expect the response to be an array , But json object not begin with array

correct api call:

```
       package com.example.lebonangle.data

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface LeBonAngleApi {

    @GET("http://192.168.1.10:8000/api/adverts?page=1")
    fun getAdverts(): Call<Advert>
}
```

correct model:

```
package com.example.lebonangle.data
    data class Advert(
         @SerializedName("@context")
        var context: String?,
        @SerializedName("hydra:member")
        var hydraMember: List<Any>?,
        @SerializedName("@id")
        var id: String?,
        @SerializedName("@type")
        var type: String?
    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but now that my "Advert" class is no longer a "List"  in my interface what do i need to put in my mainActivity for it to work well ?

Comment: You can access the list through hydraMember field of Advert class

Answer (score 0):

I have same pb.
I create class for that :

```
data class HydraMember<T> (
    @SerializedName("hydra:member")
     var hydraMember: List<T>? = null
)
```

and api calls :

```
interface myApiCalls{

    @GET("api/first_model")
    fun getFirstModels(): Call<HydraMember<FirstModel>>

    @GET("api/second_model")
    fun getSecondModels(): Call<HydraMember<SecondModel>>
}
```